# Lie groupoids as symmetries of mechanical systems?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-equations, poisson-geometry, symmetry, hamiltonian-mechanics

Lie groups are well studied as symmetries of mechanical systems in symplectic/Poisson geometry. For instance, if $G$ acts freely and properly on a mechanical system modeled by a symplectic manifold $(T^*Q,\omega_0)$ and Hamiltonian $H \in C^\infty(T^*Q)$, then it means that $\omega_0$ and $H$ are $G$-invariant, and so is the vector field describing the dynamics $X_H$. Under good conditions, one can study the properties of the reduced system on $T^*Q / G$, or perform sympletic reduction $\mu^{-1}(0) / G$ if the system admits a momentum map $\mu$.

Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G} \rightrightarrows M$ generalize Lie groups in the sense that not all arrow compositions (products) are allowed. Dependig on the point of $M$, one can act on it only by some elements of $\mathcal{G}$. In the case of $M$ being a point $\{*\}$, the actions is always possible and it corresponds to a Lie group.

What should be the properties of a mechanical system or physical system modeled using Poisson geometry in order to have a Lie groupoid as a "symmetry" analogous to the case of Lie groups? Are there typical or well known examples?

Comment: The only groupoids I know of with relationships to mechanics or physics are not "Lie" in a meaningful way.  (You can form a Lie groupoid by taking a product of a Lie group with a discrete groupoid, but the "Lie" part has nothing to do with the "-oid" part in that case.)